# Apache Webserver : What happens to requests already sent in loop after The connection has timed out

Tags: php, apache, queue

I have written a script to create Images in a loop and the loop size is almost 10K. So what happens is after certain period of time my browser shows "The connection has timed out".
But I can still see images being created in the specific folder i.e Apache is still processing my request.

The point of concern is What happens to all the HTTP Aapche server requests sent in a loop for after we get The connection has timed out.

I am really curious to know the Apache Queue system in detail.

Comment: Im very confused "What happens to all the HTTP Aapche server requests sent in a loop for after we get The connection has timed out" could you make it a bit more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) directive. There are more timeouts in place. Apache request timeout (the time Apache lets user wait for the first data). That may be different from max_execution_time in PHP. If ignore user abort is enabled, then the both timers start. After some time the Apache times out and sends back the reponse. The script in the background still runs until it either finishes or max_execution_time is reached. If you disable ignore user abort, then the script is stopped when Apache sends the timeout to user.

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

Comment: ignore_user_abort  did not help. All the HTTP requests already Queued still executing even after 'Time Out Error ' and closing the browser.

Comment: exactly. That's what `ignore_user_abort(true)` is for.

Comment: `ignore_user_abort(false);set_time_limit($yourApacheRequestTimeout)` should do the trick